# python asyncio `loop.create_task` add task in another thread's loop, the task randomly get stucked

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine, event-loop

[console's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbcmI.png)

the code:

```py
import asyncio
import time
from threading import Thread
import threading


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

def print_ids(s, l):
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name}: self: {id(s)}")
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name}: loop: {id(l)}")


class CorotineLoop:
    def __init__(self):
        # start thread
        self.thread1 = Thread(
            target=self.run_async1,
            daemon=True,
            name="one"
        )
        self.thread1.start()
        print_ids(self, loop)
        return

    def run_async1(self):
        # start loop
        print_ids(self, loop)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_forever()

    async def _run(self):
        # print stuff
        for i in range(2):
            print(threading.current_thread().name + ":", i)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        loop.close()

    def submit(self):
        # submit a task
        print("submitting...")
        loop.create_task(self._run())
        print("submitted")
        return



cloop = CorotineLoop()
cloop.submit()

print("start wating..")
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

what i'm doing is i want to create a thread simply for running async coroutines, the main thread will be running other normal sync tasks

but randomly, it stucks for no reason, sometimes ok somtimes not.

i may have it written in a wrong way, so if anyone can fix it for me?

i tried to use vscode to run debugging to find out why and where it's stucked, but it then works fine no matter how many times i've tried which leaves me no clue.

Comment: you should either be using `threading` or `asyncio`, but not both...

Comment: `Threads` - Allow parallel execution of code by running code in separate threads. ,  `Asyncio` - Allows concurrent execution of code by using a single-thread event loop.

Comment: @D.L i was just gonna use a main thread with asyncio, but before this the whole project is sync, it's hard to make users to migrate to asyncio, so i want to warp it up with another thread without changing the original method to async.

Comment: @D.L That is not good general advice.  If your asyncio application has I/O devices that lack an asyncio-aware interface, and you have to write one yourself, then threading + asyncio is virtually a requirement.  The second thread runs blocking I/O code while the main thread uses synchronization methods to allow them to play together.  That is why asyncio has functions to support exactly this approach.  Also the asyncio package itself frequently uses secondary threads under the hood.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, thank you and I actually agree with the comment that is made. However, the question did not indicate this scenario hence the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t call "create_task" from anothe thread from that in which the loop is running.

The way to do that is to use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe -

Your `submit` method can be modified like this, and if you want `_run` to be a co-routine, a wrapper synchronous function to be run in the same thread as the loop is running is needed to create a task with the co-routine

```
    def submit(self):
        # submit a task
        print("submitting...")
        def _in_thread_callback():
            loop.create_task(self._run())
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(_in_thread_callback)
        print("submitted")
        return
```

Comment: thanks!
i also found another way:
`fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._run(flow), self.loop)`

maybe it's all about `threadsafe`